# How to make zsh prompt vi mode use my .vimrc?

Tags: vim, command-prompt, zsh, vi

I am very fond of Vim, and have defined a lot of keymappings to make editing text smoother and easier. And since the zsh prompt has a vi mode, which uses the default configs of vi, I was wondering if one could tell zsh to use vi as configured in one's .vimrc.

Ideas, anyone ?

Comment: `vi` mode isn't an embedded instance of `vi`; it's just a set of key mappings (bound to shell-specific commands) that *mimic* the key bindings of `vi`.

Comment: Because of what @chepner noted above, there isn't a way to make ZSH use your .vimrc file.  However, depending on what you customized in VIM, you might be able to make the same customizations to ZSH's key bindingns.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many applications offer "vi mappings"; often, these are limited to common navigations (`hjkl`) and simple editing operations (`<C-w>`, `<C-u>`). These applications do not actually run vi / Vim; they just offer similar key bindings. The most comprehensive support I've seen is in "vi plugins" for IDEs like Eclipse that offer customization via `:map` commands. However, all of that falls short of the full Vimscript syntax that is available in your `~/.vimrc`, and all of the plugins that you may have installed.

As others have already commented, the best you can achieve is reconstructing simple remappings from your `~/.vimrc` by defining corresponding zsh key bindings (and keeping them in sync whenever you adapt or add some).

#### Alternative: Launch external Vim

Another way to get back your editing efficiency is actually using Vim to edit the command-line. I don't know about zsh in particular, but Bash offers the `fc` command for the previous command-line, can edit the current one (in `set -o vi` mode) via `<Esc>v`, and also offers a binding to `edit-and-execute-command` for insert mode, to be configured in `~/.inputrc`:

```
$if Bash
# Ctrl-F        Invoke the editor on the current command line.
#           Like c_CTRL-F in Vim.
#           Related: fc does the same for the _previous_ command.
Control-f: edit-and-execute-command
$endif
```

I guess at least some of these options are also available in zsh. The only downside to them is that the launch and quitting of Vim introduces some delay and additional keys to type, so it's only worthwhile for more complex edits of longer command-lines.

Comment: To have bash-like behavior in zsh see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6620/270482

Comment: Thanks for your answer!